# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read while there is an open stream writer

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am writing a simple selenium test in which I need to take a screenshot of webpage and save it as PDF. I am using TestNG and PDFbox library with Selenium

**Below is my test method:**

```
package com.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class ScreenshotPDF {

    @Test
    public void screenshotPDF(){

    WebDriver driver= DriverManager.getWebdriver("chrome");

    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

    try {
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);
        PDImageXObject pdi = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(screenshot ,document);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contentStream.drawImage(pdi,100,100);

        document.save("C:/Users/123456/Documents/sample.pdf");
        contentStream.close();
        document.close();
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Here when I run this test with TestNG, I get the following errors in Console:**

```
FAILED: screenshotPDF
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read while there is an open stream writer
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createRawInputStream(COSStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1177)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:372)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:561)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObjects(COSWriter.java:490)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:474)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1073)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:419)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1331)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1229)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1095)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1067)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1055)
    at com.helper.ScreenshotPDF.screenshotPDF(ScreenshotPDF.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

I did so much of googling but did not find the solution. Please help me with this error. At least what can be the reason of this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure no program has this file open?

Comment: @PeterLawrey  100% sure. 
The above test method is creating the file named sample.pdf but when I try to open it with adobe reader, it gives an error saying "The file is damaged and could not be repaired".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to close the content stream before saving:

```
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    PDImageXObject pdi = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(screenshot ,document);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
    contentStream.drawImage(pdi,100,100);
    contentStream.close(); // do this before saving!

    document.save("C:/Users/123456/Documents/sample.pdf");
    document.close();
```

Comment: If there's an example on the web (or worse, in PDFBox) with this mistake (closing of content stream after save), please mention where it is.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. The same was on pdfbox.apache.org documentation. I had gone through it one hundred time but I could not just catch it. And this is the link that you wanted : [pdfbox_inserting_image](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_inserting_image.htm)  @Tilman

Comment: Hi, my code looks exactly like that (contentStream.close() before document.save()) but I get the aforementioned error "Cannot read while there is an open stream writer". Please help? Thanks.

Comment: @Alessandro there must be some difference... make sure you're using the latest version. If it still doesn't work then create a new question with the smallest possible code that reproduces the effect. Also make sure not to have multiple versions in your class path.

Comment: By the way, how to check if PDPageContentStream is opened or closed??

Comment: @VũKhanh you can't know, there is no method. But when using a clean coding structure (e.g. JDK7 "try with resources") you won't need to know.

Comment: Thanks for this help/answer. I had this problem in my `try - catch` block while trying to get a helpful response to the client. After defining the contentStream before the _try_ and closing it in the catch block everything works :-)